# multiprocessing.pool.map and function with two arguments

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool()`

here is what i want to Pool:

```
def insert_and_process(file_to_process,db):
    db = DAL("path_to_mysql" + db)
    #Table Definations
    db.table.insert(**parse_file(file_to_process))
    return True

if __name__=="__main__":
    file_list=os.listdir(".")
    P = Pool(processes=4)
    P.map(insert_and_process,file_list,db) # here having problem.
```

I want to pass 2 arguments 
What i want to do is to initialize only 4 DB connections (here will try to create connection on every function call so possibly millions of them and cause IO Freezed to death) . if i can create 4 db connections and 1 for each processes it will be ok.

Is there any solution for Pool ? or should i abandon it ?

EDIT:

From help of both of you i got this by doing this:

```
args=zip(f,cycle(dbs))
Out[-]: 
[('f1', 'db1'),
 ('f2', 'db2'),
 ('f3', 'db3'),
 ('f4', 'db4'),
 ('f5', 'db1'),
 ('f6', 'db2'),
 ('f7', 'db3'),
 ('f8', 'db4'),
 ('f9', 'db1'),
 ('f10', 'db2'),
 ('f11', 'db3'),
 ('f12', 'db4')]
```

So here it how it gonna work , i gonna move DB connection code out to the main level and do this:

```
def process_and_insert(args):

    #Table Definations
    args[1].table.insert(**parse_file(args[0]))
    return True

if __name__=="__main__":
    file_list=os.listdir(".")
    P = Pool(processes=4)

    dbs = [DAL("path_to_mysql/database") for i in range(0,3)]
    args=zip(file_list,cycle(dbs))
    P.map(insert_and_process,args) # here having problem.
```

Yeah , i going to test it out and let you guys know.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `Pool` documentation does not say of a way of passing more than one parameter to the target function - I've tried just passing a sequence, but does not get unfolded (one item of the sequence for each parameter).

However, you can write your target function to expect the first (and only) parameter to be a tuple, in which each element is one of the parameters you are expecting:

```
from itertools import repeat

def insert_and_process((file_to_process,db)):
    db = DAL("path_to_mysql" + db)
    #Table Definations
    db.table.insert(**parse_file(file_to_process))
    return True

if __name__=="__main__":
    file_list=os.listdir(".")
    P = Pool(processes=4)
    P.map(insert_and_process,zip(file_list,repeat(db)))
```

(note the extra parentheses in the definition of `insert_and_process` - python treat that as a single parameter that should be a 2-item sequence. The first element of the sequence is attributed to the first variable, and the other to the second)

Comment: Note that the syntax `def f((arg1, arg2)):` is gone in Python 3.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: I had forgotten that. Well, unless the implementation of multiprocessing.Pool.map is different there, the way to go would be to assign to a single argument, and unpack it inside the function then.

Comment: Thanks i got it working! i got it by doing zip(file_list,cycle(dbs)). But i do not use f((arg1, arg2)). as i used more of your code i selected you!

Answer (score 8):

Your pool will spawn four processes, each run by it's own instance of the Python interpreter.  You can use a global variable to hold your database connection object, so that exactly one connection is created per process:

```
global_db = None

def insert_and_process(file_to_process, db):
    global global_db
    if global_db is None:
        # If this is the first time this function is called within this
        # process, create a new connection.  Otherwise, the global variable
        # already holds a connection established by a former call.
        global_db = DAL("path_to_mysql" + db)
    global_db.table.insert(**parse_file(file_to_process))
    return True
```

Since `Pool.map()` and friends only support one-argument worker functions, you need to create a wrapper that forwards the work:

```
def insert_and_process_helper(args):
    return insert_and_process(*args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_list=os.listdir(".")
    db = "wherever you get your db"
    # Create argument tuples for each function call:
    jobs = [(file, db) for file in file_list]
    P = Pool(processes=4)
    P.map(insert_and_process_helper, jobs)
```

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand , this is close to what i want. What i want to do is to create 4 DB Connections . One connection for each processes, but not for every function calls . `DAL("Path To db")` will create a db connection. Single connection would be slower than Quad connections at once.

Comment: I've tried those examples and it worked fine when the function doesn't have to return...; Can't we do something like my_var=P.map(insert_and_process_helper, jobs)?

Comment: Would it work if I have second argument as a list or set?

Answer (score 5):

No need to use zip. If for example you have 2 parameters, x and y, and each of them can get several values, like:

```
X=range(1,6)
Y=range(10)
```

The function should get only one parameter, and unpack it inside:

```
def func(params):
    (x,y)=params
    ...
```

And you call it like that:

```
params = [(x,y) for x in X for y in Y]
pool.map(func, params)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
from functools import partial
```

library for this purpose

like

```
func = partial(rdc, lat, lng)
r = pool.map(func, range(8))
```

and

```
def rdc(lat,lng,x):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
params=[(x,y) for x in X for y in Y]
```

you create a full copy of `x` and `y`, and that may be slower than using

```
from itertools import repeat
P.map(insert_and_process,zip(file_list,repeat(db)))
```