# Pool map with more arguments

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

How to map 2 arguments if the firs argument is `list` which has to iterate and the second shoud stay the same in each function call?

Here is the example without map to show what I really mean:

```
x = "something"
pool = Pool(4)
for code in get_codes():
    pool.apply_async(execute, args=(code,x))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Now the code using `map`:

```
pool = Pool(4)
pool.map(execute, WHAT TO PUT HERE)?

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

**Example:**

```
def print_it(x,y):
    print x,y

xs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

pool = Pool(3)

pool.map(""" map print_it on xs and y as '0'""")

pool.close()
pool.join()

1,0
0,0
2,0
3,0
5,0
4,0
6,0
```

Comment: There's plenty of material for this on SO - check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553919/passing-multiple-parameters-to-pool-map-function-in-python) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521883/multiprocessing-pool-map-and-function-with-two-arguments) thread for different ways to address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
def print_it(y,x):
    print x,y

xs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = 0

func = partial(print_it, y)

pool = Pool(3)
pool.map(func, xs)

pool.close()
pool.join()

1,0
0,0
2,0
3,0
5,0
4,0
6,0
```